# How to change default graphic size of checkboxes in treeview?

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview, c#-2.0

I want to make custom `treeview` with the `bigger checkboxes` in windows form control for easily manipulating on touch screen. But the default graphic size of the checkbox 's control in treeview is 16x16. I created new bitmap 32x32 for checkbox but the result is not as expected.

```
public TriStateTreeView() : base()
        {
         CheckBoxState cbsState;
         Graphics gfxCheckBox;
         Bitmap bmpCheckBox;

            _ilStateImages = new ImageList();
            cbsState = CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
                bmpCheckBox = new Bitmap(32, 32);
                gfxCheckBox = Graphics.FromImage(bmpCheckBox);
                switch (i) {
                    case 0: cbsState = CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal; break;
                    case 1: cbsState = CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal; break;
                    case 2: cbsState = CheckBoxState.MixedNormal; break;
                }
                CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(gfxCheckBox, new Point(0, 0), cbsState);
                gfxCheckBox.Save();
                _ilStateImages.Images.Add(bmpCheckBox);
                _bUseTriState = true;
            }
        }
```

How can I do this? How can I resize the checkbox 's size of treeview?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this, I am having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

The Checkboxes in a Treeview are only images pasted to the form, they aren't real checkboxes with all the functionality (for example you don't have native threestate mode).

You can change the images of the treeview's checkboxes by setting the `TreeView.StateImageList` [**property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.stateimagelist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> StateImageList Gets or **sets** the image list that is used to indicate the state of the TreeView and its nodes [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.stateimagelist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
// Create the StateImageList and add two images.
checkTreeView.StateImageList = new ImageList();
checkTreeView.StateImageList.Images.Add(SystemIcons.Question);
checkTreeView.StateImageList.Images.Add(SystemIcons.Exclamation);
```

Comment: I have the same issue, I have set my treeview's `StateImageList` and also set the `StateImageSize` property but something is scaling the images down when I set the size to 32x32

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: I already have a question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291184/drawing-large-checkboxes-for-treeview?noredirect=1#comment62116824_37291184