# Drawing large checkboxes for treeview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, dpi

I am trying to make my treeview's checkboxes bigger. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.stateimagelist(v=vs.110).aspx) it says by default state images are capped at 16x16 and in order to use larger state images I need to specify this entry in the app.config file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

I tried adding this to my app.config and it did not change a thing, problem is the framework seems to actually shrink the images when I use 32x32 checkboxes.

Here is how I draw and set the checkboxes in my treeview's constructor:

```
public class MultiStateTreeView : TreeView
{
    public MultiStateTreeView() : base()
    {
        ImageList ilStateImages = new ImageList();
        ilStateImages.ImageSize = new Size(32, 32);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {                                               
             Bitmap bmpCheckBox = new Bitmap(32, 32);
             Graphics gfxCheckBox = Graphics.FromImage(bmpCheckBox);                            
             switch (i)
             {                                              
                 case 0: cbsState = CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal; break;
                 case 1: cbsState = CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal; break;
                 case 2: cbsState = CheckBoxState.MixedNormal; break;
                 case 3: cbsState = CheckBoxState.UncheckedDisabled; break;
                 case 4: cbsState = CheckBoxState.UncheckedDisabled; break;
             }
             CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(gfxCheckBox, new Point(2, 2), cbsState); 
             gfxCheckBox.Save();
             ilStateImages.Images.Add(bmpCheckBox);                                 
        }

        base.CheckBoxes = true;
        this.StateImageList = ilStateImages;
    }
}
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: You want to make TreeView CheckBoxes Bigger? or Image Size?

Comment: @user6002727 The checkboxes aka the state images